# react-transition-group v2 and react-router-dom v4. Why animation change the data in both: inner and outer components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-dom, react-transition-group

I have a simple test stand of code, where we can see how the `react-transition-group` .v2 works unnormally with animations in navigation between paths via `react-router-dom` v4.

Test stand:
https://codesandbox.io/s/oxkw5prm56?from-embed

Typically, this code is just output the `string` with text of which path is currently clicked, and puts it in the page body after.

But one strange thing that `react-transition-group` .v2 in give me, it's the moment, when the path is changed and the new text is placed before the previous one is disappear - **the previous string of text replace own content with the content of the new one**. So, as you understand we have scenario with two  similar text strings after click of any path, that is incorrect.

Does someone know why it's happen? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you forgot about what is the new Transition API is. In new v4 it has uses the `location` prop  in `history` object (received from `import { syncHistoryWithStore } from 'react-router-redux'`) to suggest how the animation should update component.

So, typically the receipt in such case for you can be the next:

in `App` component add `location` prop in `Switch` section:

```
const App = withRouter(({ location }) => (
  <div>
    ....
    <TransitionGroup>
      <CSSTransition
        key={location.key}
        classNames='fade'
        timeout={1000}
      >
        <Switch location={location}> // this string is updated!
          <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
          <Route exact path='/other' component={Other} />
        </Switch>
      </CSSTransition>
    </TransitionGroup>
  </div>
))
```

Comment: Oh, this is so easy... Thank you so much!